# apache + tomcat using mod_proxy ajp randomly stops working

Tags: apache, tomcat7, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, ajp

I am using apache and mod_proxy (via ajp) to send traffic to my tomcat instance. Everything works fine and then it randomly breaks. I see a 408 in the tomcat logs and apache is returning a 503.

Has anyone seen this before? Any reason this would occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being due to the way amazon's load balancer does health checks. I ended up switching to mod_jk and using a random port for the health check to occur where normal traffic does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a firewall between Apache and Tomcat? I've had problems in the past while setting up AJP when a firewall was present. If it is your problem, take a look:

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/timeouts.html